# Spokes break loose after riding

Tags: wheels

I’m new here. I’ve been on a funny adventure through rebuilding my old city bike back wheel.

I rebuilt it from scratch. I mean lacing the spokes. It’s important to highlight that everything is old apart from the spokes and the nipples.

Everything looks fine except for the fact that the spokes get loose after riding and therefore the wheel gets wobbly.

I noticed that weight and bumping roads impact on it. I thought that I haven’t screwed the spokes enough, but today after replacing the loose spokes and making sure all were tightened enough, and going on a test ride, many spokes got loose (they dusted). My only guess is that the nipples are not the right size as the spokes or something else is off.

I got a set of Alpina 5L2D spokes 290 mm steel 14G and a pack of Alpina 5L3C spoke nipples 14G aluminium 14 mm. Judging by the name and the fact that they tighten well, they are compatible and right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To a degree, this is normal.  Newly installed spokes need to stretch and "take a set" before they will maintain a relatively constant length.  Experienced wheel builders have some tricks to deal with this, and bike manufacturers may even use a machine to perform this "break-in".

Comment: So then I'm supposed to tighten them again? The problem is that once they get loose the screw gets dusted so it won't tighten again...

Comment: Are you using a lubricant on the spoke ends?  There are "spoke prep" lubes you can put on the spoke ends to keep them from seizing while also preventing them from loosening.  (And what do you mean by "dusted"?)

Comment: I'm not lubing them. I mean that the spoke threads are not holding up the nipple firm. Like tightening them and then they get loose again while screwing.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right size nipples?

Comment: At this point not anymore, that’s why I put the specs in the question. One thing I can confirm is that it screws pretty firmly and don’t loose the treads if I try to pull the nipple out of the sole with my hands to test, but somehow when on the wheel it looses…

Comment: According to the specs they are. My other guess is the rim is a bit bent so it doesn't stay true

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the spokes tight enough?  A loose spoke will tend to "walk" itself looser.

Comment: I'm tightening them up to the level that it becomes harder to tight and it's making a noise like soft cracks and also the spoke becomes firm when checking with the fingers

Comment: If it's making a lot of  noise as you tighten it then you probably need some lubricant.

Comment: It doesn't make any noise if I screw the nipples in the spokes out of the wheel (to test it), only when assembled and being tightened.

Comment: There's no  load on the spokes when out of the wheel.

Comment: I just checked and there are multiple spokes that won't tighten anymore. It keeps spinning forever. Looks like the spokes screw threads got ripped. I have a strong feeling that the nipples are slightly bigger than the spokes. The website that sold me told me they are compatible, but I'm not convinced. Those are the specs: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14328/180650879-595820ed-10d7-4884-9d59-dc0dd129b898.jpeg

Comment: @DanielRHicks I end up rebuilding the wheel with a new set of spokes and nipples. So far so good. Nothing got loose. I'll ride a few more times before concluding it. Thanks for the help!